# cannot switch in waylan on 23.10

Tags: xorg, wayland, 23.10, community

i can only log in ubuntu Xorg why can I change that is that a bios problem or bad config?
i tried to click on wayland an when I put my password it's turn dark and and re ask me to log but when I chose ubuntu Xorg the log in is ok

Comment: You've provided no clues as to your hardware, as there are some hardware combinations that will allow login only using X.org with a default Ubuntu Desktop session (*live* or installed); this mainly applies to older hardware in my own experience.

Comment: so I should log just on Xorg?

Comment: Unless you have a specific reason or need to use Wayland, I'd just use X.org.  (FYI:  *I'm not currently running GNOME, but I'm using X.org currently myself on this Xubuntu system; but some functions are actually easier when using X.org, esp. on some hardware setups*)